# app was metadata rejected while they want me to submit a new version

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I had an app that was "**Metadata rejected**". After several rounds of correspondence they said I should submit a new version instead (to fix an issue to them). But they did not change the status to "**Binary Rejected**" and I can't upload a new version because of that!!

I reminded they in Resolution Center, but no answer for several days. I run out of solution and resubmitted metadata again just hope to catch their attention. It has been 3 days passed since then. No answer yet.

So what else I can do? Anyone hits this problem too ?

---

BTW, I hit another situation before that I think it was worth to mention here. So I had another app that was rejected but in resolution center they said "While your iTunes Connect Application State will still show as Rejected, we don't require a new binary for this type of issue ... revise the appropriate metadata values or settings, then click "**Submit New Metadata**".

But I can not find "Submit New Metadata" button at all! It took me a while to realize that was because they wrongly set app status to "Rejected" instead of "Meta Rejected". I reminded they in resolution center. No reply for several days too, so I did not know what else I can do except for submitting a new version. And that caused me about one more week (at least) to get my app approved.

Comment: Did you resolve this yet? If not, phone them directly to fix your app status: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

Comment: Thanks. They kept ignoring me (5 working days already). And finally I found that when app is "in review" status, I can reject it myself!! Then I can upload a new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting for a whole week I finally find a way to fix it. So I submitted a new metadata to change the app status to "**In Review**". Then I can reject the app myself and upload a new version!